# Counting number of binary substrings of length 3+ with one unique element

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Essentially, I'm given two lines of input. The first line is an integer length of the substring presented in the second line of input, consisting of only Gs and Hs, similar to 0s and 1s.

```
N = int(input())
chars = list(input())
lonely = 0
for i in range(3, N + 1):
  for j in range(N - i + 1):
      if ((chars[j:j + i].count('G') == 1) or (chars[j:j + i].count('H') == 1)):
          lonely += 1
print(lonely)
```

An example input is:

```
5
GHGHG
```

for which the answer is `3`: the answer is the number of the original string's substrings of length 3 or greater that only have one G or one H (this G or H is 'lonely'), and for the above sample, the substrings that meet this criterion are `chars[0:3]`, `chars[1:4]`, and `chars[2:5]`. While I think this is technically correct, there are no constraints on `N` so I am timing out for test cases where `N = 5000` and such (I have a time limit of 4 seconds per test case).

How do I work around this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effeciently remove single letter substrings from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408864/effeciently-remove-single-letter-substrings-from-a-string)

Comment: Btw, where is this from?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string on "G" and analyse the size of the left and right streak of H on each side of the splits. This will let you use compute the number of substrings with that lonely G in them.  The number of substrings for a given G split will be formed of 3 parts:  The n Hs on the left will form n-1 substrings that end with the G.  The m Hs on the right will form m-1 substrings starting with the G.  And the product of the left and right (n x m) will form substrings with the G in between Hs.

```
def count3(chars):
    count = 0
    for lonely in "GH":                 # count for G, then H
        streaks = map(len,chars.split(lonely)) 
        left    = next(streaks)         # first left side
        for right in streaks:           # get right sides
            count += max(0,left-1)      # HH...G
            count += max(0,right-1)     # G...HH
            count += left*right         # H...G...H                
            left = right                # track new left side
    return count
```

Output:

```
for testCase in ("G","GH","GHH","HG","HGH","HGHH","HHG","HHGH","HHGHH",
          "GG","HHHGHHH","GGHGG","GGH"):
    print(testCase,count3(testCase))

G 0
GH 0
GHH 1
HG 0
HGH 1
HGHH 3
HHG 1
HHGH 3
HHGHH 6
GG 0
HHHGHHH 13
GGHGG 6
GGH 1
```

Comment: I changed the solution, Initially misunderstood the question and had it only count substrings of length 3 (had a bug in it too).  I now counts substrings of all lengths >= 3

Comment: Yes, looks good now, and gave same results as the OP's on all strings I tested (all possible strings up to 16 chars, and some random strings of 1000 chars). The `if left+right>1:` isn't necessary, just an optimization, right?

Comment: Right, `if left+right>1:` wasn't necessary  (it was remnant of the previous logic)